# JavaFX disabled maximize button reappears after closing an Alert

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a JavaFX application (on OSX) which consists of a stage.
It should neither be allowed to resize it manually nor to enter full screen via the maximize button. This is currently achieved by `stage.setResizable(false)` which works fine.

The problem occurs when adding an Alert: After closing the Alert, the maximize button becomes targetable again, making it possible to enter full screen.

Here's a simple example of code:

```
// imports

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane()));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Close?");
            if (alert.showAndWait().get().equals(ButtonType.CANCEL)) {
                event.consume();
        }});
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I tested your code on Win10, and it works as you expect it to work. It may be an issue with either OSX or possibly your java version. What version are you currently running?

Comment: @HypnicJerk I'm running Java 8 (Update 131)